# Given a string how to remove surrounding quotes if they exist?

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

Given the following strings:

- Hello World
- Hello "world"
- Hello "world" hello
- "Hello World"
- "Hello World. How's life?"

What would be the best way to remove an possible string that start and end with a string. Desired return from the func would be:

- Hello World
- Hello "world"
- Hello "world" hello
- Hello World
- Hello World. How's life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about removing quotes *only* at the beginning and end of strings:

```
string.sub(/\A"/, '').sub(/"\z/, '')
```

If you mean *only* if present at both start and end:

```
string.sub(/\A"(.*)"\z/, '\\1')
```

Comment: Actually that did not work in the case where the string contains two sentences... "hello world. Hi again"

Comment: This should strip off quotes from the front and back of just about anything, including your example: `%q["Hello World. How's life?"].sub(/\A"(.*)"\z/, '\\1')` yields `"Hello World. How's life?"` but note those quotes are surrounding the Ruby string, not *in* it. Test with `puts` if you're uncertain.

Comment: what does %q[ do?

Comment: Also, how do I use that with a variable in side?

Comment: FYI, that doesn't work. Going from `s = s.sub(/\A"(.*)"\z/, '\\1')` to    `s= %q["s"].sub(/\A"(.*)"\z/, '\\1')` now just returns `s`

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? None of your examples have just a single quoted word in them.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the new recommendation. Would you mind updating your answer? Thanks

Comment: FYI, this ended up working perfectly `s.gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, '')`

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use `s` or `string`, but `%q["s"]` is asking for the literal string `"\"s\""`, it has nothing to do with the variable. Maybe you're thinking of `%Q["#{s}"]`?

Answer (score 1):

Using numbered saves (sometimes called "registers") and sed it's pretty easy:

```
$ cat quotes
Hello World
Hello "world"
Hello "world" hello
"Hello World"
"Hello World. How's life?"
$ cat quotes | sed 's/^\(\"\)\(.*\)\1$/\2/'
Hello World
Hello "world"
Hello "world" hello
Hello World
Hello World. How's life?
```

The sed script says: "at the beginning of the line ^, if there is a one double quotation mark " store it \("\) in numbered save one, store anything else \(.*\), as far as numbered save one at the end of the line $, in numbered save two, then replace the whole thing by numbered save two (the anything else between the double quotation marks). If there is no quotation mark at the beginning, numbered save one is empty, and if there is one at the beginning but none at the end, then the pattern doesn't match.
There are other scripting languages such as perl that handle regular expressions easily.

Comment: P.S. I'm sorry, I didn't see that you were asking specifically about Ruby, which I don't know anything about. But if Ruby understands regex, then you might be able to use the same expressions.

Comment: It's generally not recommended to post answers in a language other than what's requested. This clutters up the answers with things that aren't solutions.

Comment: sorry, not sure how to do this in ruby. This did not work `s = s.sub('s/^\(\"\)\(.*\)\1$/\2/')`